user unable to write to media | Permission denied
I am having a problem utilizing a mounted drive
on my Raspberry Pi 2B running Diet Pi.
dietpi@DietPi:/media/dietpi/Other$ sudo chmod 666 -R /media/dietpi
dietpi@DietPi:/media/dietpi/Other$ touch text.txt
touch: cannot touch 'text.txt': Permission denied
dietpi@DietPi:/media/dietpi/Other$ 

The media appears to be mounted correctly
as I am able to read what is in the drive.
Other Steps Attempted
sudo chown -R dietpi /media/dietpi

This returns numerous of the following error:
chown: changing owndership '/media/dietpi/<file/dir>: Operation not permitted


Check /etc/mtab or /proc/mounts - is it mounted rw?

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

@waltinator These disks have only ever been utilized on Debian-based GNU/Linux systems

@waltinator I mounted it utilizing mount /dev/sdb1 /media/<username>/<partition name>. Do I need to specify it for mount to have read and write privileges? How would I verify /etc/mtab or /proc/mounts? Thank you so much for your help.

How exactly did you get it mounted? What's the filesystem type?

To check /proc/mounts, run e.g. grep /media /proc/mounts. The error message chown: changing ownership <path>: Operation not permitted is typical and expected for filesystems that cannot store Unix-style file permissions for individual files/directories. We need to identify the filesystem type (listed in /proc/mounts): for such filesystems, mount options can usually be used to adjust the permissions filesystem-wide, but those options are specific to each filesystem type/family.

By doing a recursive chmod 666,
you have turned off the x (execute) permission bits
on all the directories on the drive. 
Try
find /media/dietpi -type d -exec chmod +x {} ';'

If that results in permission errors, run it with sudo.
